# How to link javascript functions with applet?

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to make a form page in a java applet. Now after making textbox and submit button, how can I validate this text-box? Anyone if can tell me if I can link JS code to applet and if yes, then how?

```
package com.tcs.applet;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyApplet extends Applet  { 
TextField inputLine = new TextField(15);  
private JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
public MyApplet() {
    add(inputLine);
   add(button);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Package netscape.javascript provides Java code(your applet code) the ability to access the JavaScript engine in the web browser.

for more info you can check following

[Netscape Doc](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

On the **action performed**  of the `JButton` do your validation.

If there is wrong input in textfield then throw a acception.

Comment: Thanks...Means I need to validate it here in applet code only or shall I create a seperate JS file for that including this function?

Comment: Yes, Validate it here only. That is good practice for learner.

Comment: I have to start countdown in next page and this countdown shud start from the digit entered in the textbox. For example, if I enter 8, then countdown should start from 8 in the new window, down to 0 and then the window should get closed automatically.. I am not getting any idea regarding this... :( Plz help.

Comment: for that you need thread.Read the data from textfield using `getText()`. Parse your `getText()` output into Integer. Now give this integer value to your window. Apply thread implimentation in your window. use `sleep()` method of thread and keep dicreasing the counter. If counter reaches to 0 then dispose your window using `dispose()` method.